# Does there exist a Bash equivalent to concatenation from the Plan 9 rc shell?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

In the Plan 9 `rc` shell,
one can write

```
echo (foo bar baz)^.c
```

to get

```
foo.c bar.c baz.c
```

or

```
echo (foo bar baz)^(.c .h .o)
```

to get

```
foo.c bar.h baz.o
```

Is there an equivalent to this in Bash?
Specifically,
is there a quicker way than
`` `for f in foo bar baz; do echo $f.c; done` ``
for the former,
and does such a method exist for the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) for the first case:

```
$ echo {foo,bar,baz}.c
foo.c bar.c baz.c
```

(Note: this doesn't work for lists stored in variables, because brace expansion takes place before variable expansion.)

But I don't think there's a way to get it to zipper two lists together (like Plan 9's `echo (foo bar baz)^(.c .h .o)`). If you use brace expansion with two lists, it gives you all possible combinations:

```
$ echo {foo,bar,baz}{.c,.h,.o}
foo.c foo.h foo.o bar.c bar.h bar.o baz.c baz.h baz.o
```